# How I can control the length of the string that I want to enter during runtime and then reallocate the memory to store larger string?

Tags: c, string, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

For example, I want to enter a string that can store only five elements. It can be *"Hello"*, but if I enter more than 5 elements like *"Hello World"*. It stores only the *"Hello"* part. And I want to control the size or the number of elements that I enter inside the string using the `malloc()` function. So that I can later change the size of the string using `realloc()` to store a much larger string like *"Hello World"* or concatenate the original string with a new string, just like we do by using the `strcat()` function.

I am new to C and English is not my first language. So, if there is any part that you don't understand, please let me know.

Is it possible?

Comment: One option is to use `getchar` in a loop. Store its result for the first five characters and then just don't store any remaining characters that you want to ignore.

Comment: If you're on a Unixy system, there's `getline()` which does that for you

Answer (score 0):

For many applications simple use a large buffer ...

```
#define LINE_SIZE 100  // Be generous in size
char buf[LINE_SIZE];
```

... and read a *line* of user input with `fgets()`.

```
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  // Success!

  // If deisred, lop off potential trailing \n
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
```

After reading the line into a *string*, then parse the string for "the number of elements".

You cannot control what a user types in.  Code can control how it handles the input.  Be prepared for incorrect, foolish and hostile input.

---

Advanced: If you want unlimited length inputs (be careful what you wish for), more advanced strategies and code are needed to handle memory allocation/reallocation.